# use Application_MAPILogonComplete and WithEvents in Module instead of ThisOutlookSession in Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-office, outlook-2013

Right now all of my VBA code is in `ThisOutlookSession`. I want to put everything in a module so I can export it and other folks can import it without having to muck around with their own `ThisOutlookSession`. I want it to be easy for the user -- the user just imports my module file.

My code depends on `Application_MAPILogonComplete` and `WithEvents`. Neither of these are available/work in a module.

I see that classes have a `Class_Initialize` but it only triggers when a class object is initialized so I'd still need some kind of `Application_MAPILogonComplete` event.

Is there anyway to do what I want? Keep everything in a module or class that can be exported and imported that has code run when Outlook opens and supports `WithEvents` so I can execute a function when new e-mails are added to a folder?

Comment: http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=28

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you but I am aware of that information.

Answer (score 0):

Only an object can handle events, so you need a class - `ThisOutlookSession` is one, but if you want to modularize your code you'll need to have a *class module* to do that work.

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents App As Outlook.Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set App = Application
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set App = Nothing
End Sub

'select "App" from the left-hand dropdown at the top of the code pane.
'then select the event(s) you want to handle from the right-hand dropdown;
'the VBE will automatically generate the handler(s) with the correct signature.
```

All that's left to do is to have an actual instance of that class (let's say it's called `Class1`) - you'll want to create that instance in `ThisOutlookSession`

```
Option Explicit
Private AppEvents As Class1

Private Sub Application_Quit()
    Set AppEvents = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set AppEvents = New Class1
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there no way to do it without having to edit/modify `ThisOutlookSession`?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan you could always have an auto-instantiated object in a standard module, e.g. `Private AppEvents As New Class1` - but I'd be more inclined to trust using `ThisOutlookSession` as an entry point works perfectly fine and reliably. Auto-instantiated objects (`As New`) are always kind of weird.

Comment: When I add `Dim AppEvents As Class1` then `Set A = New Class1` to a `public sub` in a module and run it the `Class_Initialize` function **does** fire. When I try `Dim AppEvents As New Class1` in a `public sub` or `Private AppEvents As New Class1` in the top of the module then the `Class_Initialize` function **does not** fire.

Comment: Yeah see `As New` is weird. Declarations aren't executable, so the object only gets *actually* created when the identifier is referred to by the first executable statement that gets to it.